# Background image for v-card component Vuetify not showing

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

Hello I'm trying to add a background image to a v-card component using the img prop as indicating in the documentation for Vuetify as follows:

```
<v-card img="../assets/gradient.svg"> </card>
```

I have had constant issues in loading images on Vue by just using the relative path as above or by even using ("~" or "@") to force it as a module request. But I managed to fix them using require(), though this time with the img prop it doesn't seem to be working.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a min-width and min-height on the card.
If the path is correct to the image it will show up.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
<v-card :img="require('../assets/gradient.svg')"> </card>
```

this is because you're grabbing an image locally instead of a hosted URL.